# 'React' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module error with js-jest

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, jsx, ts-jest

I'm using `ts-jest`. I recently removed a bunch of `import React from "react"` statements from my code. My jest tests started failing with this error:

> 'React' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module

I found a lot of answers to similar questions but nothing that solved the issue for me. So, posting to answer.

This is my `jest.config.js` file:

```js
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  rootDir: 'tests',
  globalSetup: '<rootDir>/jest.setup.js',
  globalTeardown: '<rootDir>/jest.teardown.js',
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      tsconfig: {
        jsx: 'react',
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing the `jsx: 'react'` line to `jsx: 'react-jsx'` solved it for me.

```js
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  rootDir: 'tests',
  globalSetup: '<rootDir>/jest.setup.js',
  globalTeardown: '<rootDir>/jest.teardown.js',
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      tsconfig: {
        jsx: 'react-jsx',
      },
    },
  },
};
```